# Apache Spark metrics on Prometheus - not working with custom location( spark.metrics.conf="<location>/metrics.properties"

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, metrics

I'm trying to expose Apache Spark metrics to Prometheus, and running into issues when i try to use custom location for metrics.properties
(ref - https://dzlab.github.io/bigdata/2020/07/03/spark3-monitoring-1/)

When i use the $SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties, this works fine :

Here are the steps :

1. started apache spark master & slave
2. started spark slave
3. started spark shell

Commands :

```
bin/spark-shell --master spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077 \
    --conf spark.ui.prometheus.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.executor.processTreeMetrics.enabled=true
```

changes to prometheus.yaml

```
  - job_name: "spark_driver"

    metrics_path: "/metrics/prometheus/" 
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:4040"]
  
  - job_name: "spark_executor"

    metrics_path: "/metrics/executors/prometheus/" 
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:4040"]
 - job_name: "spark_worker"

    metrics_path: "/metrics/executors/prometheus/" 
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8081"]
  - job_name: "spark_master_master"

    metrics_path: "/metrics/master/prometheus/" 
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8080"] 
      
  - job_name: "spark_master_applications"

    metrics_path: "/metrics/applications/prometheus/" 
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8080"]
```

Curl shows the metrics :

```
# metrics_executor_* 

curl -s http://localhost:4040/metrics/executors/prometheus/
spark_info{version="3.2.0", revision="5d45a415f3a29898d92380380cfd82bfc7f579ea"} 1.0
metrics_executor_rddBlocks{application_id="app-20220824151351-0000", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_memoryUsed_bytes{application_id="app-20220824151351-0000", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_diskUsed_bytes{application_id="app-20220824151351-0000", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_totalCores{application_id="app-20220824151351-0000", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_maxTasks{application_id="app-20220824151351-0000", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_activeTasks{application_id="app-20220824151351-0000", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0

# metrics_app_*
    
(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-2.32.1.darwin-amd64 karanalang$ curl -s http://localhost:4040/metrics/prometheus/
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_disk_diskSpaceUsed_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_disk_diskSpaceUsed_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOffHeapMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOffHeapMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOnHeapMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20220824151351_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOnHeapMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 868

# metrics_worker_*
# metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_*

(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-2.32.1.darwin-amd64 karanalang$ curl -s http://localhost:8081/metrics/prometheus/
metrics_worker_coresFree_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_worker_coresFree_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_worker_coresUsed_Number{type="gauges"} 8
metrics_worker_coresUsed_Value{type="gauges"} 8
metrics_worker_executors_Number{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_worker_executors_Value{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_worker_memFree_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 6144
metrics_worker_memFree_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 6144
metrics_worker_memUsed_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 1024
metrics_worker_memUsed_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 1024
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_fileCacheHits_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_filesDiscovered_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_hiveClientCalls_Count{type="counters"} 0


# metrics_master_*

(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-2.32.1.darwin-amd64 karanalang$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/metrics/master/prometheus/
metrics_master_aliveWorkers_Number{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_master_aliveWorkers_Value{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_master_apps_Number{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_master_apps_Value{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_master_waitingApps_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_master_waitingApps_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_master_workers_Number{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_master_workers_Value{type="gauges"} 1
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_fileCacheHits_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_filesDiscovered_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_hiveClientCalls_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_parallelListingJobCount_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_partitionsFetched_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_Count{type="histograms"} 0

# metrics_application

(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-2.32.1.darwin-amd64 karanalang$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/metrics/applications/prometheus/
metrics_application_Spark_shell_1661379231055_cores_Number{type="gauges"} 8
metrics_application_Spark_shell_1661379231055_cores_Value{type="gauges"} 8
metrics_application_Spark_shell_1661379231055_runtime_ms_Number{type="gauges"} 3409139
metrics_application_Spark_shell_1661379231055_runtime_ms_Value{type="gauges"} 3409139
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_fileCacheHits_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_filesDiscovered_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_hiveClientCalls_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_parallelListingJobCount_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_HiveExternalCatalog_partitionsFetched_Count{type="counters"} 0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_Count{type="histograms"} 0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_Max{type="histograms"} 0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_Mean{type="histograms"} 0.0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_Min{type="histograms"} 0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_50thPercentile{type="histograms"} 0.0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_Max{type="histograms"} 0
metrics_CodeGenerator_compilationTime_Mean{type="histograms"} 0.0
```

However, when i try to specify a different location for metric.properties,
it is not showing the metrics

Steps :

1. remove/rename the $SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties -> $SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties.old
2. copy the metrics.properties to new location
3. start spark master & slave
4. spark-shell command specifying the spark.metrics.conf="/metrics.properties

Here is the spark-shell command :

```
bin/spark-shell --master spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077 \
    --conf spark.ui.prometheus.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.executor.processTreeMetrics.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.metrics.conf="/Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/prometheus_metrics/metrics.properties"
```

When i do the curl, metrics are being shown only for port 4040 (not for ports 8081, 8080 i.e. the master & the worker metrics):
Curl commands to port 8080, 8081 is showing me the html page instead

```
Curl output for port 8081 :

</html>(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-2.32.1.darwin-amd64 karanalang$ curl -s http://localhost:8081/metrics/prometheus/ 
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/webui.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/timeline-view.css" type="text/css"/><script src="/static/sorttable.js"></script><script src="/static/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script src="/static/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script><script src="/static/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script><script src="/static/initialize-tooltips.js"></script><script src="/static/table.js"></script><script src="/static/timeline-view.js"></script><script src="/static/log-view.js"></script><script src="/static/webui.js"></script><script>setUIRoot('')</script>
        
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"></link>
        <title>Spark Worker at 192.168.8.100:51307</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h3 style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="/">
                  <img src="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"/>
                  <span class="version" style="margin-right: 15px;">3.2.0</span>
                </a>
                Spark Worker at 192.168.8.100:51307
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="row"> <!-- Worker Details -->
        <div class="col-12">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><strong>ID:</strong> worker-20220825120759-192.168.8.100-51307</li>
            <li><strong>
              Master URL:</strong> spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077
            </li>
            <li><strong>Cores:</strong> 8 (8 Used)</li>
            <li><strong>Memory:</strong> 7.0 GiB
              (1024.0 MiB Used)</li>
            <li><strong>Resources:</strong>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <p><a href="http://192.168.8.100:8080">Back to Master</a></p>
        </div>
      </div><div class="row"> <!-- Executors and Drivers -->
        <div class="col-12">
          <span class="collapse-aggregated-runningExecutors collapse-table" onClick="collapseTable('collapse-aggregated-runningExecutors',
              'aggregated-runningExecutors')">
            <h4>
              <span class="collapse-table-arrow arrow-open"></span>
              <a>Running Executors (1)</a>
            </h4>
          </span>
          <div class="aggregated-runningExecutors collapsible-table">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">ExecutorID</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory</th><th width="" class="">Resources</th><th width="" class="">Job Details</th><th width="" class="">Logs</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>RUNNING</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="1024">
        1024.0 MiB
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><strong>ID:</strong> app-20220825121611-0000</li>
          <li><strong>Name:</strong>
          <a href="http://192.168.8.100:4040"> Spark shell</a>
          </li>
          <li><strong>User:</strong> karanalang</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://192.168.8.100:8081/logPage/?appId=app-20220825121611-0000&amp;executorId=0&amp;logType=stdout">stdout</a>
        <a href="http://192.168.8.100:8081/logPage/?appId=app-20220825121611-0000&amp;executorId=0&amp;logType=stderr">stderr</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
          </div>
          
          
          
        </div>
      </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>(base)


Curl output for port 8080 :
(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-2.32.1.darwin-amd64 karanalang$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/metrics/master/prometheus/
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/webui.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/timeline-view.css" type="text/css"/><script src="/static/sorttable.js"></script><script src="/static/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script src="/static/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script><script src="/static/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script><script src="/static/initialize-tooltips.js"></script><script src="/static/table.js"></script><script src="/static/timeline-view.js"></script><script src="/static/log-view.js"></script><script src="/static/webui.js"></script><script>setUIRoot('')</script>
        
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"></link>
        <title>Spark Master at spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h3 style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="/">
                  <img src="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"/>
                  <span class="version" style="margin-right: 15px;">3.2.0</span>
                </a>
                Spark Master at spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><strong>URL:</strong> spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077</li>
              
              <li><strong>Alive Workers:</strong> 1</li>
              <li><strong>Cores in use:</strong> 8 Total,
                8 Used</li>
              <li><strong>Memory in use:</strong>
                7.0 GiB Total,
                1024.0 MiB Used</li>
              <li><strong>Resources in use:</strong>
                </li>
              <li><strong>Applications:</strong>
                1 <a href="#running-app">Running</a>,
                0 <a href="#completed-app">Completed</a> </li>
              <li><strong>Drivers:</strong>
                0 Running,
                0 Completed </li>
              <li><strong>Status:</strong> ALIVE</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div><div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span class="collapse-aggregated-workers collapse-table" onClick="collapseTable('collapse-aggregated-workers','aggregated-workers')">
              <h4>
                <span class="collapse-table-arrow arrow-open"></span>
                <a>Workers (1)</a>
              </h4>
            </span>
            <div class="aggregated-workers collapsible-table">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Worker Id</th><th width="" class="">Address</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory</th><th width="" class="">Resources</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://192.168.8.100:8081">
              worker-20220825120759-192.168.8.100-51307
            </a>
      </td>
      <td>192.168.8.100:51307</td>
      <td>ALIVE</td>
      <td>8 (8 Used)</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="7168.1024">
        7.0 GiB
        (1024.0 MiB Used)
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span id="running-app" class="collapse-aggregated-activeApps collapse-table" onClick="collapseTable('collapse-aggregated-activeApps','aggregated-activeApps')">
              <h4>
                <span class="collapse-table-arrow arrow-open"></span>
                <a>Running Applications (1)</a>
              </h4>
            </span>
            <div class="aggregated-activeApps collapsible-table">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Application ID</th><th width="" class="">Name</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Resources Per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">User</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Duration</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app/?appId=app-20220825121611-0000">app-20220825121611-0000</a>
        <form action="app/kill/" method="POST" style="display:inline">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="app-20220825121611-0000"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="terminate" value="true"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to kill application app-20220825121611-0000 ?')) { this.parentNode.submit(); return true; } else { return false; }" class="kill-link">(kill)</a>
      </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://192.168.8.100:4040">Spark shell</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        8
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="1024">
        1024.0 MiB
      </td>
      <td>
        
      </td>
      <td>2022/08/25 12:16:11</td>
      <td>karanalang</td>
      <td>RUNNING</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="4567980">
        1.3 h
      </td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div>
          
        </div><div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span id="completed-app" class="collapse-aggregated-completedApps collapse-table" onClick="collapseTable('collapse-aggregated-completedApps',
                'aggregated-completedApps')">
              <h4>
                <span class="collapse-table-arrow arrow-open"></span>
                <a>Completed Applications (0)</a>
              </h4>
            </span>
            <div class="aggregated-completedApps collapsible-table">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Application ID</th><th width="" class="">Name</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Resources Per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">User</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Duration</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div>
          
        </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>



(base) Karans-MacBook-Pro:prometheus-2.32.1.darwin-amd64 karanalang$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/metrics/applications/prometheus/
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/webui.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/timeline-view.css" type="text/css"/><script src="/static/sorttable.js"></script><script src="/static/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script><script src="/static/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script><script src="/static/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script><script src="/static/initialize-tooltips.js"></script><script src="/static/table.js"></script><script src="/static/timeline-view.js"></script><script src="/static/log-view.js"></script><script src="/static/webui.js"></script><script>setUIRoot('')</script>
        
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"></link>
        <title>Spark Master at spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h3 style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="/">
                  <img src="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"/>
                  <span class="version" style="margin-right: 15px;">3.2.0</span>
                </a>
                Spark Master at spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><strong>URL:</strong> spark://Karans-MacBook-Pro.local:7077</li>
              
              <li><strong>Alive Workers:</strong> 1</li>
              <li><strong>Cores in use:</strong> 8 Total,
                8 Used</li>
              <li><strong>Memory in use:</strong>
                7.0 GiB Total,
                1024.0 MiB Used</li>
              <li><strong>Resources in use:</strong>
                </li>
              <li><strong>Applications:</strong>
                1 <a href="#running-app">Running</a>,
                0 <a href="#completed-app">Completed</a> </li>
              <li><strong>Drivers:</strong>
                0 Running,
                0 Completed </li>
              <li><strong>Status:</strong> ALIVE</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div><div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span class="collapse-aggregated-workers collapse-table" onClick="collapseTable('collapse-aggregated-workers','aggregated-workers')">
              <h4>
                <span class="collapse-table-arrow arrow-open"></span>
                <a>Workers (1)</a>
              </h4>
            </span>
            <div class="aggregated-workers collapsible-table">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Worker Id</th><th width="" class="">Address</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory</th><th width="" class="">Resources</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://192.168.8.100:8081">
              worker-20220825120759-192.168.8.100-51307
            </a>
      </td>
      <td>192.168.8.100:51307</td>
      <td>ALIVE</td>
      <td>8 (8 Used)</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="7168.1024">
        7.0 GiB
        (1024.0 MiB Used)
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span id="running-app" class="collapse-aggregated-activeApps collapse-table" onClick="collapseTable('collapse-aggregated-activeApps','aggregated-activeApps')">
              <h4>
                <span class="collapse-table-arrow arrow-open"></span>
                <a>Running Applications (1)</a>
              </h4>
            </span>
            <div class="aggregated-activeApps collapsible-table">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Application ID</th><th width="" class="">Name</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Resources Per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">User</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Duration</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app/?appId=app-20220825121611-0000">app-20220825121611-0000</a>
        <form action="app/kill/" method="POST" style="display:inline">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="app-20220825121611-0000"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="terminate" value="true"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to kill application app-20220825121611-0000 ?')) { this.parentNode.submit(); return true; } else { return false; }" class="kill-link">(kill)</a>
      </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://192.168.8.100:4040">Spark shell</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        8
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="1024">
        1024.0 MiB
      </td>
      <td>
        
      </td>
      <td>2022/08/25 12:16:11</td>
      <td>karanalang</td>
      <td>RUNNING</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="4605276">
        1.3 h
      </td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div>
          
        </div><div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <span id="completed-app" class="collapse-aggregated-completedApps collapse-table" onClick="collapseTable('collapse-aggregated-completedApps',
                'aggregated-completedApps')">
              <h4>
                <span class="collapse-table-arrow arrow-open"></span>
                <a>Completed Applications (0)</a>
              </h4>
            </span>
            <div class="aggregated-completedApps collapsible-table">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Application ID</th><th width="" class="">Name</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Resources Per Executor</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">User</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Duration</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><div>
          
        </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

metrics.properties:

```
# Example configuration for PrometheusServlet
*.sink.prometheusServlet.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet
*.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/prometheus
master.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/master/prometheus
applications.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/applications/prometheus
```

What needs to be done to debug/fix this ?
tia !